# Pick next line from cin

Tags: c++

How do I check the length of next line without extracting it from cin?

I have the input data in following form:

```
A
-B
--*
--C
-D
--E
---*
---F
0
```

And I have a recursive function to Build a tree from it.

```
TreeNode* BuildTree() {
  string line;
  getline(cin, line);
  char id = line[line.size() - 1];
  if (id == '0') return NULL;
  TreeNode* n = (id == '*') ? NULL : new TreeNode(id, NULL, NULL);
  if (/* This line's size less than next line's size */) {
    n->left = BuildTree();
    n->right = BuildTree();
  }
  return n;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your code so that you're one line ahead.  Then your if-statement becomes:

```
if (/* this line's size is greater than the previous line's size */) {
   ....
}
```

Alternately, if you can afford the memory (and likely you can), slurp the entire file into a `vector<string>` and then recurse on *that*.